# How to Convert Obj to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this Json Obj

```
{
    "key": 111,
    "Students":{
       "AddressInfo":{
         
       }
    }
}
```

Now I need to convert to Array as shown:

```
{
    "key": 111,
    "Students":[
       {
       "AddressInfo":{

       }
      }
    ]
}
```

And lastly how do I add position of the Object after Key value
So the final Json Array should like

```
{
    "key": 111,
    "Students":[
       {
       "AddressInfo":{

       }
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: your json is not valid

Comment: This is not a valid array

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  The desired result is not a valid JavaScript object structure.  To serialize data to a custom format you need to write custom code which serializes to that format.

Comment: @tknkrtl -This is a valid JSON

Comment: @Konrad - This is a valid JSON

Comment: No it's not. An array does not have a string key, as you've put `AddressInfo` as a key

Comment: @Cjmarkham -Ah yes sorry its a typo

Comment: a) it's not valid and b) there's no such thing as "JSON object" or "JSON array". It's an object or an array, there's no JSON involved here.

Comment: @Cjmarkham - Yes I have changed the syntax. Thanks for finding

Comment: You've now removed the `position` from the bottom code snippet, making your second question irrelevant. I'd suggest removing that question so the original can be reopened if you want help.

Comment: things started to get out of hand...

Answer (score 2):

```js
const obj = {
    "key": 111,
    "Students":{
       "AddressInfo":{
         
       }
    }
}

obj.Students = [obj.Students]

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Beautiful!

It won't do what he wants, but it will do what he _said_ he wants!